# Barplot no R: Auxílio com os argumentos para criar um gráfico mais completo

Tags: r, rmarkdown, barplot

Olá. Necessito criar os dois gráficos abaixo, dessa exata forma. Certos ajustes, como por exemplo:

- a criação de um valor 7 no eixo x, o qual foi omitido;
- o eixo horizontal com traços de cada valor;
- a legenda rotacionada de cada barra no segundo gráfico;
- as linhas de grade do fundo do gráfico, relativas a cada valor do eixo y e setas dos eixos;

Gráfico 1:

[image: Gráfico 1]

Gráfico 2:
[image: Gráfico 2]

O que fiz até aqui:

```
Acidentes_ATA <- read_excel("~/R/PROVA MAURI/Acidentes ATA.xlsx")
View(Acidentes_ATA)
dput(Acidentes_ATA)
structure(list(Acidentes = c(3, 5, 4, 0, 4, 4, 4, 1, 4, 2, 4, 
3, 8, 6, 4, 4, 1, 4, 1, 3, 3, 1, 2, 2, 6, 0, 2, 1, 3, 2), Ano = c(1977, 
1978, 1979, 1980, 1981, 1982, 1983, 1984, 1985, 1986, 1987, 1988, 
1989, 1990, 1991, 1992, 1993, 1994, 1995, 1996, 1997, 1998, 1999, 
2000, 2001, 2002, 2003, 2004, 2005, 2006)), row.names = c(NA, 
-30L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))

frequencia_acidentes <- table(Acidentes_ATA$Acidentes)
barplot(frequencia_acidentes, ylab="Frequency", xlab="Number of Accidents", ylim=c(0, 10), col="skyblue1", space=0, main="Fatal Commercial Airplane Accidents per Year (1977-2006)")
barplot(dbinom(0:12, 11000000, 0.0000004), ylab="Probability", xlab="Number of Accidents", xlim=c(0,13), ylim=c(0,0.25), col="skyblue1", space=0)
```

[image: Meu Gráfico 1]
[image: Meu Gráfico 2]

Comment: Bem-vindo ao StackOverflow em Português! Infelizmente, esta pergunta não pode ser reproduzida por quem for tentar respondê-la. Por favor, dê uma olhada [neste link](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/6700/como-fazer-uma-pergunta-reproduz%C3%ADvel-em-r/6701#6701) (principalmente no uso da função `dput`) e veja como fazer uma pergunta reproduzível em R. Assim, as pessoas que desejarem te ajudar conseguirão fazer isto da melhor maneira possível.

Comment: Editado. Muito obrigado e perdão a burrice.

Answer (score 1):

Consegui alguns parâmetros. Faltam outros.

```
barplot(frequencia_acidentes, ylab="Frequency", xlab="Number of Accidents", ylim=c(0, 10), col="skyblue1", space=0, main="Fatal Commercial Airplane Accidents per Year (1977-2006)")
grid(nx=NA, ny=NULL, lty=1)
barplot(frequencia_acidentes, ylab="Frequency", xlab="Number of Accidents", ylim=c(0, 10), col="skyblue1", space=0, main="Fatal Commercial Airplane Accidents per Year (1977-2006)", add=TRUE)
axis(2, at=seq(0,9,1), labels=seq(0,9))
abline(h=0)
distribuição_1 <- dbinom(0:12, 11000000, 0.0000004)
barplot(distribuição_1, ylab="Probability", xlab="Number of Accidents", xlim=c(0,13), ylim=c(0,0.25), col="skyblue1", space=0)
axis(side=1, at=seq(1,12), labels=seq(1,12), cex.axis=1)
grid(nx=NA, ny=NULL, lty=1)
barplot(distribuição_1, ylab="Probability", xlab="Number of Accidents", xlim=c(0,13), ylim=c(0,0.25), col="skyblue1", space=0, add=TRUE)
abline(h=0)
```

[image: Gráfico 1]
Nesse acima falta incluir a barra do número 7 (que possui frequência 0 e o R omitiu), e traçar as linhas inferiores.

[image: Gráfico 2]
Já nesse falta centralizar os valores do eixo x (centro das barras), plotar as legendas de cada barra (probabilidades).

Comment: Para ter a barra 7, tente `table(factor(Acidentes_ATA$Acidentes, levels = 0:8))`. Isto inclui o valor 7 com frequência zero na contagem de casos (`table`).

Comment: Deu certo. Obrigado

Answer (score 0):

Consegui os textos das barras dessa forma, através de tentativa e erro:

`text(x=c(0.5, 1.5, 2.5, 3.5, 4.5, 5.5, 6.5, 7.5, 8.5, 9.5, 10.5, 11.5, 12.5), y=c(0.0125, 0.054, 0.08, 0.135, 0.152, 0.13, 0.085, 0.078, 0.043, 0.021, 0.009, 0.004, 0.001), labels=c("0.012", "0.054", "0.119", "0.174", "0.192", "0.169", "0.124", "0.078", "0.043", "0.021", "0.009", "0.004", "0.001"), srt=90, adj=0)`

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]